# Kotlin, Android - How do i post the same runnable inside the runnable?

Tags: android, kotlin, runnable

I want to post a runnable to a view object inside a runnable , currently i am stuck here.

```
 var runnable = Runnable {
        if(numLinesToDraw >= amplititudes.size){

        }
        else
        {
            numLinesToDraw = numLinesToDraw ++
            invalidate()
            postDelayed({

            },2000)
        }
    }

    postDelayed(runnable,2000)
```

As you can see , there is a `postDelayed` method inside the runnable. What i want to do is post the same runnable again and so on. What should i add here?

```
       postDelayed({

        },2000)
```

Comment: use `this`? At least it works this way for Java. `postDelayed(this,2000)`

Comment: If this is a periodic callback, I'd add `removeCallbacks(this)` at the beginning of runnable as well, just to be safe it never "doubles up" and runs too often.

Answer (score 8):

In Kotlin 1.2+, you can define a local `lateinit var` for the `runnable` and then ititialize it with a `Runnable` that uses the variable:

```
lateinit var runnable: Runnable
runnable = Runnable {
    /* ... */
    postDelayed(runnable,2000)
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Do like this,

```
var myRunnable: Runnable = object : Runnable {
    override fun run() {
        progressHandler.postDelayed(this, 100) // here is self calling
    }
}
```

Comment: This solution works, if use lambda, the **this** pointer could not be found.